# SQL not returning similar data in Access and .Net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, ms-access-2010, vb.net-2010

FYI:  creating Windows desktop application using VS 2010 and Access 2010

I have come across some odd behavior in VB.Net while trying to query and access database.  I have an SQL script that, when run in Access, produces a dataset with records.  But, when I run the same script in VB.Net (which connects to the same access db) the query produces no results.  Here is my .Net script:

```
Dim strConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & item.Text
Dim conn As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter
Dim s As String = " SELECT" & vbCrLf _ 
   & "  GrantData.[Grant Number]," & vbCrLf _
   & " OutputData.[Output], " & vbCrLf _
   & " OutputData.PlanNumber, " & vbCrLf _
   & " OutputData.ActualNumber" & vbCrLf _
   & " FROM " & vbCrLf _
   & " Themes, " & vbCrLf _
   & " GrantThemes, " & vbCrLf _
   & " GrantData," & vbCrLf _
   & " OutputData" & vbCrLf _
   & " WHERE" & vbCrLf _
   & " Themes.ThemeID = GrantThemes.ThemeId AND" & vbCrLf _
   & " GrantData.[Grant Number] = GrantThemes.[Grant Number] AND" & vbCrLf _
   & " GrantData.[Grant Number] =OutputData.[Grant Number] AND" & vbCrLf _
   & " ( " & vbCrLf _
   & " (GrantData.Status in ('Cleared', 'Completed', 'Closed')) AND" & vbCrLf _
   & " (Themes.Theme Like '*infrastructure*' or Themes.Theme Like '*construction*')" & vbCrLf _
   & " )" & vbCrLf _
   & " ORDER BY" & vbCrLf _
   & " GrantData.[Grant Number];"


conn = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(strConnectionString)
conn.Open()
Try
   da = New OleDbDataAdapter(s, strConnectionString)
   da.Fill(ds, sqlStatement)   
Catch ex As Exception   

Finally
End Try
```

So, like I said, if I run this, the data set is empty (I have a break point on ds and can view the dataset).  But, if I put a break point on the SQL string and copy it into the Access Database, it runs just fine.  Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: There's also no need for all those carriage returns and line feeds... You can improve the readability just by doing what you've got there, without the ` & vbCrLf`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a problem with the `Like` wild cards.

Although this works inside an Access session ...

```sql
Themes.Theme Like '*infrastructure*' or Themes.Theme Like '*construction*'
```

You need to substitute `%` for `*` with OleDb ...

```sql
Themes.Theme Like '%infrastructure%' or Themes.Theme Like '%construction%'
```

Or, if you prefer a query which will give you the same results from OleDb as it does in Access, use `ALike` instead of `Like`.

```sql
Themes.Theme ALike '%infrastructure%' or Themes.Theme ALike '%construction%'
```